# Not able to start the Spring-Boot sample

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I was trying out spring-boot samples. This is specifically the example [spring-boot-sample-tomcat](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat), that I have been trying to run.

As instructed, I have run `mvn package` and it is successful.
But when running the jar `java -jar target/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-0.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar`, I am getting the below exception.

Please confirm if there is any jars which need to be put in the classpath.
Or what to do to make it run.

Link to the [pom.xml](https://raw.github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat/pom.xml) which is being used.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1935)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.findClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:110)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:65)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: Please post your `pom.xml`; you're missing some dependency.

Comment: I was able to clone the spring-boot-sample-tomcat directory and run the two commands you've shown and get it running as expected. Check your versions of maven and java using `mvn --verison` and `java -version`. I have Apache Maven 3.0.4 and java version "1.6.0_51".

Comment: I'm far from an expert in maven but I beleive you may need to have a version in your pom file  spring-webmvc dependency entry like the following: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: You don't have to specify the version because Spring Boot provides versions for everything by default. You can override if you wish, but otherwise, you are using Boot's pre-set versions. This is what's provided by the already included parent pom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try adding this segment to your pom:

```
<properties>
  <start-class>org.springframework.boot.sample.tomcat.SampleTomcatApplication</start-class>
</properties>
```

This defines the "main" to use explicitly. Spring boot is supposed to pick up the main automatically, but being explicit is a good way to go. That was the only way I was able to get another project I was working on to work using the "java -jar" invocation working.

Answer (score 1):

I just executed:

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git merge upstream/master
Already up-to-date.
$ cd spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat/
$ mvn clean package && java -jar target/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-0.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
...
Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
...
2013-09-23 08:52:33.713  INFO 698 --- [           main] o.s.b.s.tomcat.SampleTomcatApplication   : Starting SampleTomcatApplication on retina with PID 698 (/Users/gturnquist/src/spring-boot/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat/target/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-0.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar started by gturnquist)
2013-09-23 08:52:33.753  INFO 698 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@21301fa: startup date [Mon Sep 23 08:52:33 CDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
2013-09-23 08:52:34.673  INFO 698 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2013-09-23 08:52:34.674  INFO 698 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
2013-09-23 08:52:34.753  INFO 698 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2013-09-23 08:52:34.754  INFO 698 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1004 ms
2013-09-23 08:52:34.902  INFO 698 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.s.tomcat.SampleTomcatApplication   : ServletContext initialized
2013-09-23 08:52:34.918  INFO 698 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2013-09-23 08:52:34.919  INFO 698 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2013-09-23 08:52:34.991  INFO 698 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2013-09-23 08:52:35.127  INFO 698 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.boot.sample.tomcat.web.SampleController.helloWorld()
2013-09-23 08:52:35.169  INFO 698 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2013-09-23 08:52:35.169  INFO 698 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2013-09-23 08:52:35.377  INFO 698 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 458 ms
2013-09-23 08:52:37.548  INFO 698 --- [           main] o.s.b.s.tomcat.SampleTomcatApplication   : Started SampleTomcatApplication in 4.299 seconds
```

Perhaps you need to update your clone and rebuild?

Comment: I am studying an app that you personally help develop.  Are you willing to look at a question I have about it?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655518/disable-confirmation-page-in-spring-oauth2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my problem was that I had the wrong class configured on start-class under properties, once I removed it, everything was fine:

```
<properties>
  <start-class>wrong class here</start-class>  <-- REMOVE THIS LINE
</properties>
```