# disable confirmation page in Spring OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I am studying Spring OAuth2 by decomposing the set of [three interconnected sample apps at this GitHub link](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2).  The apps work as intended on my devbox, but the `authserver` app produces an unwanted confirmation page that asks the user to confirm that they authorize the client at `localhost:8080/login` to receive their protected information. A screen shot of the confirmation page is as follows:

[image]

**What specific changes need to be made to the `authserver` app's code to remove the confirmation step?**

I understand that the confirmation page could be useful in certain use cases.  But the confirmation page is not appropriate for the use case that I have in mind, so how can I disable this step?

---

**FIRST ATTEMPT:**

---

I have located the view code for the authorization page in [`authorize.ftl`, which you can read by clicking on this link](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/resources/templates/authorize.ftl).  But when I do `Ctrl-H` in an eclipse workspace and search for "authorize.ftl", no results show up.  Similarly, I reviewed the [Spring OAuth2 Developer Guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html#customizing-the-ui).  Some mention in the guide is made of creating a separate `@RequestMappig("/oauth/authorize")`, but it did not seem clear how to disable this confirmation step.

The code for the template `login` view is in [`login.ftl`, which you can read at this link](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/resources/templates/login.ftl).

**Is the solution to simply move the `login.ftl` code into a new `login.html` file, and then manage that view with `@RequestMappig("/oauth/authorize")`?**

If I interpret the working from the Developer Guide link above correctly, it seems to say that

1.) an `@RequestMappig("/oauth/authorize")` method linked to GET would serve up the login view, then another `@RequestMappig("/oauth/authorize")`,

2.) then another `@RequestMappig("/oauth/authorize")` method linked to POST would take the information from the view and bypass the confirmation step.

**But what would this look like in code?**  Here is a starting point, if I understand correctly:

```
`@RequestMappig("/oauth/authorize", method = RequestMethod.GET)`
public @ResponseBody SomeType method1Name(){
    SomeType st = new SomeType();
    //do some stuff to st
    return st;
}

`@RequestMappig("/oauth/authorize", method = RequestMethod.POST)`
public @ResponseBody SomeType method2Name(){
    SomeType st = new SomeType();
    //do other stuff to st
    return st;
}
```

What do I put in the methods?  And then were do I put the view code?

The Developer Guide says to start with [`WhiteLabelApprovalEndpoint,java`, which you can read on GitHub at this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint.java).

Comment: authserver uses Spring Security OAuth2 as an OAuth2 implementation?

Comment: @ksokol That is my understanding.  Why do you ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User confirmation of the token grant is optional. You need to register the client as autoapprove="*" if you want to skip that step. I'm pretty sure that's in the user guide.